# How to read data between xml tags with attributes in javascript/ionic without using DOM/ActiveXObject?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ionic-framework

I simply need to extract some info between two tags, in this case, `<wsse:BinarySecurityToken>`

For example:

```
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken att1="abc" att2="cd3"  att3="adfa">This is a text I need!!!===</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
```

I tried

```
match = text.match(/<wsse:BinarySecurityToken[.*]>([^<]*)<\/wsse:BinarySecurityToken>/g)
```

does't work!

Or is there anything better than regex? I use *angularJs 1*

Comment: This is not duplicate. I do not want to use `DOM/ActiveXObject`.

Comment: Take a look at [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/jEbLv2/1). This should work I guess.

Comment: You should include in the question itself that it is for an ionic app, not in a comment to the answers (btw I deleted mine). But did you tried the DOMParser from your app ? I see plenty of examples online that make use of it, so I'd guess it's available even though I don't know ionic at all. Ps: I won't undelete my answer since if I'm correct, it's still a dupe.

Comment: The regex worked. Thanks @Kaiido anyway for your answer, I wanted to avoid DOM.

Comment: [You should not try to avoid the right tools for the right job.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do:

```
match = text.match(/<tag1.*>([^<]*)<\/tag1>/g)
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Please can you answer for the updated question? I tried and this is not working!

Comment: Thanks this worked. I had to tweak it for my updated question , but this worked! `/<wsse:BinarySecurityToken.*>([^<]*)<\/wsse:BinarySecurityToken>/`